# Faster response in Query

Tags: terracotta

I am new to SAG's IBO stack and exploring the capabilities in Terracotta.My use case is to query multiple data sources (stored in db or cache) and present the query response as fast as possible.Using db,we can very well use JOINs (LEFT Outer join in my use case) and present the query response.We are trying to use Terracotta to store the data for faster query response.But since JOINs are not recommended in Terracotta caches and also LEFT OUTER JOIN is not supported,are there any other design approaches to explore apart from keeping a de-normalized cache structure? Thanks.